# What is the difference between Hadoop fs and regular Unix commands?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and HDFS, I am trying to see why the Hadoop fs commands are needed versus just using the Unix command equivalents. They both seem to work, my first thought was the Hadoop command interfaced directly with the HDFS namenode and propagated it to all nodes. However this seems to be the case when I use just the Unix shell command. I poured over the internet and did not find an easy explanation. Help is greatly appreciated. Or a link to an explanation of the difference.

Comment: What environment are you in where you can use UNIX commands on HDFS?  HDFS NFS or HDFS Fuse?  UNIX command might work on the underlying HDFS files but the names are mangled to relate the namenode and for replication.

Comment: HDFS over NFS which is packaged by MAPR.  So I am manipulating these files on a mounted volume on an edgenode(not part of the cluster) but has mapr software on it.  When I run the unix commands or the hadoop -fs command they seem to produce same results.  I am wondering if the env is so small(6) nodes that an automated replication happens or something so I do not need the hadoop command line.  `[root@maprprod01 bin]# ./hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.0-mapr-1710`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on HDFS over NFS then you can expect most simple commands to work properly (such as `ls`, `cd`, `mkdir`, `mv`, `rm`, `chmod`, `chgrp`, `chown`).  The only need for the `hadoop fs` or `hdfs dfs` command is if you are using extended ACLs or want to do other Hadoop specific things like:

- alter the replication factor `hadoop fs -setrep`
- remove files under /user/*USERNAME*/.Trash `hdfs dfs -expunge`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the commenters TK421 it made me think that this is over NFS and its also not straight HDFS, Its a MAPR implementation so it differs, I found some documentation from mapr that explains.

> You can also set read, write, and execute permissions on a file or
>   directory for users and groups with standard UNIX commands, when that
>   volume has been mounted through NFS, or using standard hadoop fs
>   commands.

https://mapr.com/docs/52/MapROverview/c_volumes.html

Answer (score 0):

The File System (FS) shell includes various shell-like commands that directly interact with the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) as well as other file systems that Hadoop supports, such as Local FS, HFTP FS, S3 FS, and others. The FS shell is invoked by:

```
bin/hadoop fs <args>
```

All FS shell commands take path URIs as arguments. The URI format is scheme://authority/path. For HDFS the scheme is hdfs, and for the Local FS the scheme is file. The scheme and authority are optional. If not specified, the default scheme specified in the configuration is used. An HDFS file or directory such as /parent/child can be specified as

> hdfs://namenodehost/parent/child

or simply as

> /parent/child

(given that your configuration is set to point to hdfs://namenodehost).

Most of the commands in **FS shell behave like corresponding Unix commands**.

You may not find some regular shell commands like -head, but -tail and -cat are available. Subtle differences in the same commands can be [found for individual commands here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I’ve seen that in the docs. I guess my question is what’s the difference if I use the Hadoop -fs commands versus just Unix commands. Will using standard CHMOD modify all the the nodes on the HDFS? It seems to work that way. I see the same results when using both the Hadoop -fs commands and standard shell commands. Sorry if not clear.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Hadoop fs commands were probably designed keeping in mind the unix commands. However, not all of them behave in similar manner (especially for additional flags, like "hadoop fs -ls" behaves like "ls -al" command). As mentioned earlier hadoop fs commands are a subset, and you may not find all the unix commands.